# Using flex the child div is the same height as the child image

Tags: html, css

I have two childs in a flexbox, there is an image and a div, however the divs height is being set based on the height of the image, I don't expect this behavior since I am not using a grid.

This is a snippet to reproduce my issue, The expected result should be the div should only take up height of the content inside it.

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <img class="responsive-img" src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20230511/ourmid/pngtree-isolated-cat-on-white-background-png-image_7094927.png" />
  <div class="content-box"></div>
</div>

<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 6px;
}

.responsive-img {
  height: 21.688rem;
}

.content-box {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 23.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a; /* This is an approximation for "dark-n-10". Adjust to the exact color you need. */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `align-items: start;` to the flex-container has fixed the issue.

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 6px;
  align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <img class="responsive-img" src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20230511/ourmid/pngtree-isolated-cat-on-white-background-png-image_7094927.png" />
  <div class="content-box"></div>
</div>

<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 6px;
  align-items: start;
}

.responsive-img {
  height: 21.688rem;
}

.content-box {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 23.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a; /* This is an approximation for "dark-n-10". Adjust to the exact color you need. */
}
</style>
```

Comment: FYI: The reason you need to change the `align-items` property is because the default value is `normal`, which behaves like `stretch` when using `flex` - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#values)